# C# Selenium IF & ELSE

Tags: c#, selenium

For some reason my if & else statement aren't working correctly, code example:

```
             if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a")).Displayed)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).Click();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Heannaannay");
        }
```

What's suppose to happen is if

```
if (driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a")).Displayed)
```

then follow through with the commands,

```
 else
```

print ...

but it doesn't seem to do that, it just searches for the if statement within a 10 second limit and then if the specified element isn't displayed it will throw an exception rather than producing the else statement..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `driver.FindElement` will throw an exception when it can't find the element. What you need is using `FindElements` to check if the element is existed before checking the `Displayed`.

```
if (driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a")).Count > 0 && driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a")).Displayed)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a")).Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).Click();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Heannaannay");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `FindElement` method throws an exception if the element you're looking for is not present in the DOM. This is by design of the WebDriver API. The API expects that you know the state of the page you're automating, and that implies that you will never attempt to find an element that isn't present on the page. If you do attempt to find an element, and the element doesn't exist, that's an exceptional condition, and therefore means that throwing an exception is the correct thing to do. This would be far more readily apparent if you restructured your code to something like the following:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a"));
if (element.Displayed)
{
    element.Click();
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).Click();
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Heannaannay");
}
```

In this case, it would be abundantly clear that the `FindElement` call is what's throwing the exception, and preventing the evaluation of the boolean `Displayed` property.

Answer (score 0):

I know you accepted an answer but there's a more efficient way to do what you are attempting. You don't need to scrape the page multiple times,

1. Get all the elements that match your first locator.
2. Make sure that there is at least one element in the collection (check `.Any()`).
3. Make sure the first element is displayed. If it is, click on the first element in the collection, and so on.

   ```
   IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb']/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/a"));
   if (links.Any() && links.ElementAt(0).Displayed)
   {
       links.ElementAt(0).Click();
       driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='gb_71']")).Click();
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Heannaannay");
   }
   ```